# generar pdf con jquery y php desde una modal

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

solo les pedimos algún ejemplo, estamos implementando un sistema de registro de mascotas, después de haber registrado a la mascota deseamos nos genere una ficha en pdf con todos los datos de la mascota, estos datos se encuentran en una modal con un botón que dice exportar, lo que queremos que al momento de dar clic en el botón exportar se debe de generar un pdf con los datos de la macota, dejamos una imagen para que comprendan. 
Nota: el sistema está en php

[image: Modal]

Comment: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Comment: Algún ejemplo...

Comment: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/html2pdf/acid.html

Answer (score 0):

Podrías realizar una llamada AJAX con los datos contribuidos en el formulario y generar un PDF con [HTML2PDF](https://html2pdf.fr/es/home) (Es una librería bastante robusta, fácil de usar y personalizar) tienes ejemplos por [aquí](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/tree/master/examples).